# php mail error message & not working

Tags: php, html

I have a form where users report posts. They insert message id in a text box and choose from a number of radio buttons to which the report applys to and then send the form.

 form:...

```
    <form method="post" action="sendmail.php" name="Email form">
Message ID <input type="text" name="message id" /><br/><br/>
Aggressive conduct <input type="radio" name="option1" value="aggressive contact" /><br/><br/>
Offensive conduct <input type="radio" name="option2" value="offensive conduct" /><br/><br/>
Rasical conduct <input type="radio" name="option3" value="Rasical conduct" /><br/><br/>
Intimidating conduct <input type="radio" name="option4" value="intimidating conduct" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Mail" />
</form>
```

the sendmai.php file...

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "message id\option1\option2\option3\option4";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('info@uni-lad.com', 'report!!', $message);
?>
```

Im getting the error message:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or
>   custom "From:" header missing in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\sendmail.php on line 9

how do i ressolve this? Also i get the feeling that all this wont send the input the user gives

can anyone help?

Comment: It's only a warning (which you should fix), so it should be sent all the same. Only fatal errors stop execution.

Answer (score 3):

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: @David Sajdak Should i leave the '$message = "message id\option1\option2\option3\option4";' part in and change the rest?